# Exception "The SSL connection could not be established." when using Yarp.ReverseProxy in Docker linux container

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, reverse-proxy, ms-yarp

I have an error

```
Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder[48]

      Request: An error was encountered before receiving a response.

      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.

       ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.

       ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094419:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert access denied

         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

         at Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)

         at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions, SelectClientCertificate clientCertificateSelectionCallback)

         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)

         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder.SendAsync(HttpContext context, String destinationPrefix, HttpMessageInvoker httpClient, ForwarderRequestConfig requestConfig, HttpTransformer transformer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

my appsetting.json file:

```
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "route1" : {
        "ClusterId": "redditCluster",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "{**catch-all}"
        }
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "redditCluster": {
        "Destinations": {
          "reddit/destination1": {
            "Address": "https://www.reddit.com/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

my program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapReverseProxy();
app.Run();
```

My Dockerfile is default.

I get this error immediately after starting the application.

When I run this app with the "https" configuration it works properly, but with the "Docker" configuration I get an error.

When i change the line `"Address": "https://www.reddit.com/"` to `"Address": "https://www.google.com/"` in appsetting.json file it works fine.

Comment: See : https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/